# Ansible - Unarchive module overwriting

Tags: ansible

i am working with ansible and using a playbook.
In this playbook I am performing a download (from a web url) and unarchive of a file into hosts (using unarchive module), and after that I am copying some files from control machine into hosts (using copy module).

What is happening is that every time I use unarchive module, although every file is the same, ansible is overwriting files in hosts. 
How can I make it so that it does not overwrite if contents are the same?

My playbook:

```
---
- hosts: group1
sudo: yes
tasks:

  - name: Download and Extract apache
  unarchive:
   src: http://mirrors.up.pt/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.1/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.1.tar.gz
   dest: /opt/
   remote_src: yes

- name: Copy file to host
  copy: src=/etc/ansible/files/myfile.xml dest=/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.1/conf/myfile.xml
```

Comment: Frankly speaking: you can't. This is one of these operations, that are too complex for Ansible to handle idempotently. Starting with the basic dilemma: what if some file exists in the destination, but not in the archive... On the other hand, overwriting the files with the same content doesn't really change the state, so a requirement "*not overwrite if contents are the same*" is just a request for optimisation -- however, most modules in Ansible that behave idempotently on the surface perform copy-and-compare operations in background -- there is really little space to improve.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However using [creates] option seems to work.

Comment: `creates` works, but it doesn’t do what you asked for. It is a simple flag. If a file exists, then unarchive process is skipped. It doesn’t check the contents.

Comment: You *could* use `keep_newer` if you're using 2.1 or later, and have the job touch the file(s) after the unarchive. It doesn't actually scan the contents, but won't overwrite files newer than the version in the archive, which they then would be by default. That has the advantage of timestamping files with the install date, but the significant disadvantage of hiding the actual timestamp from the archive.

Neither of these methods does exactly what you ask, but either could be used to accomplish what you seemed to want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `creates` option referencing something the unarchive places.

c.f. the documentation page [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/unarchive_module.html) (check the version against what you are using.)

e.g.:

```
- unarchive:
    remote_src : yes
    src        : "{{ url }}"
    dest       : "{{ install_dir }}/"
    creates    : "{{ flagFile }}"
```

If the unarchive creates a /tmp/foo directory with a file named bar, then flagFile can be /tmp/foo/bar, and unarchive won't run again if it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this multiple ways, depending on the situation.

**Option 1:**
One of the files created by the archive has a specific name, such as `foo-version_no`
In this case, I can add the option:
`creates: 'foo=version_no'`

If this file exists, ansible will not extract it.
**Caveat:**
If the extracted directory is supposed to contain 12 files, and at least 1 of them has been removed or altered, the unarchive module will not replace them.

**Option 2:**
If there is no version number in the file name, examine one of the files in the extract directory and asses if it is the correct file.
Perhaps a checksum on the file; a grep for a unique parameter; or executing a command with the '--version' option.
Register the results into a variable:
`register: correct_file`

The unarchive command can then have the when parameter:
`unarchive:
. . .
. . .
when: (correct_file.stdout != My_Required_Version and  correct_file is defined)`

The last part, about being defined, is there because, if you determine the extracted files don;t exist at all, you would skip checking the version, so the variable 'correct_file' will be undefined.
**Caveat:**
See Caveat from Option 1.

**Option 3:**
Use an argument, or extract command that will not over write files if they have not changed.
**Caveat:**
There will still be a little over head, because the extract command needs to asses each file, but will not make a new one.

**Option 4:**
Have another way to assess the quality of the files in the extracted directory, and set a variable based upon that result.
A simple example would be to run a checksum on all files, the run a checksum on that output, yielding a "Checksum of Checksums"
Ex:
`curr_sum=$( cksum $( cksum /path/to/extracted/files/* ) )
if [ $curr_sum -eq $Correct_Value ]
then
echo "This is OK"
exit 0
else
echo "This is not ok"
exit 1
fi`

In ansible, you would run this command and register the result. Then compare the output to the pre-set value:
`cmd: "script_name"
register: cksum_answer
failed_when: failed
. . .
unarchive:
. . .
. . .
when: cksum_answer.rc == 1`